# Escaping only specific tags in grails

Tags: html, grails, formatting, xss

In my application users will be able to put their own content. Of course I want to secure my application for XSS attacks. But using `.encodeAsHTML()` escapes everything. I'd like to let the users style their text, so I'd like some tags to be unescaped, like `<b>, <i>, <u>`. Any idea how I can do that? Or maybe someone already did something similar? I thought also about BBCode style formatting - anyone did it on grails?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which lets you whitelist tags and attributes, but otherwise scrub your HTML.

Here's an example:

```
String escapeNonFormattingHTML(String unescaped) {
    def whitelist = Whitelist().simpleText() //allows b, i, u, em, strong
    return new Jsoup().clean(unescaped, whitelist)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Html cleaner](http://grails.org/plugin/html-cleaner) plugin can help you clean html based on whitelists. But other tags won't be escaped but removed completely. Its based on jsoup.